# How to pass partial view name via variable?

Tags: asp.net, partial-views

I'd like to  render different partial views by some condition.
How can I pass the partial view name in variable? It may be filed in main view, JS variable, ViewBag field?

```
<div class="modal-body" id="div_partialProp">
<form>
@{
//await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_EditProperties");
await Html.RenderPartialAsync(partialPropViewName);//<--??
}
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you want to pass it from? Usually you have a field in the viewmodel which you can use to determine what to do in the view, ie. select correct partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a string variable and store the name of the partial view into that variable and pass that variable to `RenderPartialAsync` as below:

```
   @{
      string partialPropViewName = '_EditProperties';
    }
    <div class="modal-body" id="div_partialProp">
    <form>
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync(partialPropViewName);//<--??
     }
    </form>
    </div>
```